# Unhandled exception at 0x00C61540 in Project3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000003

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error whenever run this program a second time. Basically what it does is it writes some information to a file, creating the file if it doesn't exist. However, when it runs the second time, it needs to read the previously created file, which for some reason throws an exception, and I get this error:

Unhandled exception at 0x00C61540 in Project3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000003.

The debugger points to line 15 in the function getBalance as the place where the exception is thrown. However, I actually call this function more than once, and it only throws the exception the second time I call it.

```
int getBalance(int lineno){ // Funciton to convert strings in file to ints
    string balance;
//Getting information from the file about locations
int *pointer;
pointer = findNewLines();
static int linenopos[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    linenopos[i] = *(pointer + i);
}

int balanceInt;

//Opening file
balanceFile.open("E:\\MoneyStuff\\balance.txt", ios::in | ios::out); //Exception is thrown here

//Getting Balances
balanceFile.seekg(linenopos[(lineno - 1)], ios::beg);
getline(balanceFile, balance);

balanceFile.close();

stringstream convert(balance);//Variable to convert string balance to integer balance

//Converting balance string to int
convert >> balanceInt;

//Setting balanceInt to 0 if the file doesn't exist
if (balanceInt < -30000)
    balanceInt = 0;

return balanceInt;
}
```

**Edit**: Okay so I corrected the part in my code where I was trying to access an element in an array that doesn't exist, but I'm still getting the same exception. The exception only seems to happen when I try to read from a previously created file, so could it have to do with permissions?

Note: This is my first time asking a question here, so if I need to give you guys more code or more information, please tell me! Thanks

Comment: A few other problems besides your main one: you should initialize `balanceInt`, or check whether `>>` fails. As you have it, if `convert >> balanceInt` fails (e.g. `balance` did not contain a readable integer) then you access an uninitialized value when you check against `-30000`.

Comment: Also you must check that `lineno > 0` and `lineno <= 10` before doing `linenopos[lineno - 1]`. It would be a thousand times better if you change your code so that `findNewLines` returns a `vector<streampos>` . Then there is no size limitations, and you can use the `.at()` member function of vector to avoid out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare an array with **10 elements**, it means your indexes goes from `0` to `9`.

Adjust the loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Trying to access an element that doesn't exist in the array will cause weird behaviors, and **crash** is one of them.

As for the exception caused by `open()`, catch it and print to the screen to have some clues of what's going on:

```
try {
    balanceFile.open("E:\\MoneyStuff\\balance.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
}
catch (const std::exception& e ) {
     std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, technically, it could do _anything,_ not just crash, but +1 since this is almost certainly the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for this info, I didn't know that when you declared it it didn't count from 0... However, I tried this and its still throwing the same exception. Also, it only happens when I read from a created file, so I don't think this is the problem

Answer (score 1):

If the error code is saying "Access violation reading location 0x00000003", then that means you're trying to read a value from null+3.

Your findNewLines() function probably isn't returning what you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop has `11`, see:

```
static int linenopos[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
```

the correct would be "10":

```
static int linenopos[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

But the best way is to count the items before the loop (any chance you will upgrade your vector), try:

```
static int linenopos[10];

int size = sizeof(linenopos) / sizeof(linenopos[0]);//count items

for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
```

or use vector size, like this:

```
const int size = 10;//vector size

static int linenopos[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
static int linenopos[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
```

you iterate past the end of the linenopos array.

You should have

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to learn how to format code in your posts.